# downloading a large file in java

Tags: java, url, fileutils

here is my code for downloading a file from a webpage and saving it in a path:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

public class Demo2 {
    public static void main(String...args){

        try {
            URL url = new URL("ftp://ftp.fu-berlin.de/pub/misc/movies/database/crazy-credits.list.gz");
            FileUtils.copyURLToFile(url, new File("D:\\imdb\\credits.list.gz"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

I'm getting a connection timed out exception:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at sun.net.ftp.impl.FtpClient.doConnect(FtpClient.java:958)
    at sun.net.ftp.impl.FtpClient.tryConnect(FtpClient.java:918)
    at sun.net.ftp.impl.FtpClient.connect(FtpClient.java:1013)
    at sun.net.ftp.impl.FtpClient.connect(FtpClient.java:999)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.ftp.FtpURLConnection.connect(FtpURLConnection.java:294)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.ftp.FtpURLConnection.getInputStream(FtpURLConnection.java:393)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1037)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyURLToFile(FileUtils.java:1460)
    at plotgz.Demo2.main(Demo2.java:14)
```

I'm unable to figure out what exactly is the issue as it works fine for other urls like:

> http://www.vtuplanet.com/d.php?type=papers&file=B.E+%28Engineering%29%2FComputer+Science+%28CSE%29%2FSem+5%2FDBMS%2FDBMS+Notes+%5B2010%5D+%28SJBIT%29.pdf

Can someone please help me with this? thanks in advance!!

Comment: Well it sounds like the connection to ftp.fu-berlin.de has timed out, given the error message... are you able to download that URL with a browser?

Comment: check below link and try to do it asynchronously http://stackoverflow.com/questions/921262/how-to-download-and-save-a-file-from-internet-using-java

Comment: The FTP port at that location is not open in its firewall. Nothing you can do about it from the client end. @ChiragArora Async I/O won't solve this problem. You can't even do async I/O if you can't create a connection.

Comment: @Jon Skeet yes i am able to download that that URL with a browser

Comment: is there no way to solve this?

Comment: The code works fine for me. It's probably something with the network configuration.

Comment: I can download file with your code. Check your network firewall

Comment: Also check your proxy configuration.